# When I try to submit a custom form in wordpress to a template page I get warnings and it fails to post

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

**Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/woo_commerce/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 766
Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/woo_commerce/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2212**

There are going to be multiple fields of the same name so I am send and array but on post i get the above warnings and it says *http://localhost:8888/woo_commerce/checkout-2/* page not found
it works if I give different names to all the fields and not put them in an array. 
Here is the my code :

```
                  <h3>Products</h3> 
                    <div class="row">  
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product</label> <a  id="link-1" target="_blank" style="display: none;"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a>
                                  <input class="form-control keyword keyword1" id="keyword_1" data-id="1"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                                 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="p_id-1" name="product[id]" >
                                 <i id="search1" class="fa fa-search common"></i>
                                <i id="spinn1" class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin common1" style="display: none;"></i>
                               </div>
                            </div>      
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">  
                      <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <span id="p_img-1"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeAqpCWozaKHNPdGE7_sulC_tJSL9MuuqsJP6k9D-u83_NKv2ozw&s"></span>
                      </div>    
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Qty</label>
                          <input class="form-control stocks" id="stock-1" type="number" name="product[quantity]" min="0" max="0" step="1" value="1">

                       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: check this - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-strip_tags-error/ https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string/

Comment: trim() and strip_tags() works only on string and you are giving it an array.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I get this error when I post the form to the other page. I am not using trim or strip_tags()